# Disable resume for all apps

Tags: macos

I would like to disable resume for all applications  by default (including newly install applications).

I know the following command will disable resume for a specific application (Safari in this case) 
`defaults write com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false` but I was wondering if there's a way to disable it permanently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable resume for all applications permanently, in the Finder, press Shift-Command-G to "Go to the folder" ~/Library/Saved Application State/, then press Command-I to Get file info, and check the "locked" box to lock the folder. This will keep any newly installed applications from resuming.

Answer (score 5):

Uncheck `Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps` under 
`System Preferences -> General`.

In Mountain Lion, this option has been changed to read, `Close windows when quitting an application` with fine print to explain that open documents will not be restored.

Comment: This did not work for me. The application continue to resume, even when I uncheck it.

Comment: @doc_180 The first time you open an app after unchecking that box, it will still restore windows on the next launch, but it shouldn't do so on subsequent launches. This is because the app's info is still in the "Saved Application State" folder when the setting is unchecked. The next time the app launches, that info will be removed. If it still doesn't work, you may want to try Daniel's solution

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that it is not respected when using the `shutdown` command or when deciding to install updates. In both cases it will restart all the previous apps with all its previous windows.

Answer (score 2):

Or use the Resuminator app:

http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/26/dear-aunt-tuaw-help-me-fine-tune-session-window-restores/

Allows both fine tuning or global toggle of Resume.